# How to block main thread until Intent service completes?

Tags: android

```
Program structure :

Service (running in main thread) {

start intent service 1
start intent service 2

// here I have to wait until both intent services have completed. They don't return any data.
//... some code
}
```

I looked at a similar question on SOF - [Android:: Blocking main thread for worker thread to finish before executing other tasks in main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976069/android-blocking-main-thread-for-worker-thread-to-finish-before-executing-othe), but it didnt' help.

Comment: it has the answer there I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.  If you block the main thread, your phone will appear to be frozen, and eventually the app will be killed or at least prompt the user to kill it.  Instead, you want your intent services to return a result to the activity, and for the activity to keep track of which ones have returned.  When they both have, it should then do the appropriate processing.  But under no circumstances should you block the main thread.

Comment: The problem is : I need data from intent service(s) to continue execution of my main service :) . So, unless I know that I've received data, it makes no sense for me to continue execution of the main thread

Comment: @kalyanpvs - till what time?. I've a backed singleton model. My Intent service updates it. When the update is done, I can continue in my main service. I'll  need to conyinuously check whether data has been updated or not. OR have a result receiver with a countdown latch

Comment: @WhoAmI Then return from whatever function you're in (so the main thread gets back to its looper and can continue to process events).    But don't just block, it will make your app look unprofessional and you will eventually be killed.

Comment: @WhoAmI You don't need to continually monitor.  This is event driven programming.  You don't block, you wait for events- in this case a return from the intent service.  Just like when you're not doing anything while waiting for UI you don't block, you wait for android to call you.

Comment: @WhoAmI until you will get data to update..if data is available then update it otherwise wait for it..dont check continuously write some callback methods and notify when data is available..

Answer (score 1):

you **can not block main thread**.intent service not mean to be made for blocking main thread but it work as temp background service that have a particular task and reporting to main thread when task is completed.

**so you can not block but you can put other logic that will execute after intent service task completed**. (it will notify in broadcast receiver when task completed so you can use broadcast receiver which will called when intent service task completed).